# Scheme - 'application: not a procedure' error

Tags: scheme

I have the following program:

```
(define (myFunc x e)
  (let loop ((n x) (m e) (acc 2))
    (cond   
    ( (eqv? (abs (-   ( * (expt -1 (+ acc 1)) (/ (expt n acc) acc) )    ( * (expt -1 (+ acc 1)) (/ (expt n (- acc 1) ) (- acc 1)) ) )) m)
      (begin  (display "result is: ") (display acc) #f))
    (else
        (loop (n) (m) (+ acc 1))

    ))
  ))
```

You can see that it calculates values, check for an equality, and if it does not succeed it repeats the loop.

However, when i run it i get the error:

> application: not a procedure;
>   expected a procedure that can be
>   applied to arguments
>   given: 0.5
>   arguments...: [none]

Pointing to the loop (n) part after my 'else' statement.
Why is this happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n` and `m` are (I presume) numbers, not procedures. You can't call them. And yet, when you say `(n)` and `(m)`, that's exactly what you're trying to do. It's equivalent to the expressions `n()` and `m()` in JavaScript.

Remember, in Scheme, `(foo bar baz)` is equivalent to the likes of `foo(bar, baz)` in JS, and `(foo)` is equivalent to `foo()`, and `((foo))` is equivalent to `foo()()`. You cannot add parentheses willy-nilly.

Comment: so i guess i just need to call the loop with m and n without the parenthesis?